# How to find multiple values on three parallel arrays using count occurence algorithm

Tags: python

I have to find the number of pupils who achieved 75% or more in three different exams. I wrote the code in two different versions where version 2 is successful but I am unable to find the correct value from version 1.

**Version 1**

```
literacy = [42,72,80,82,76]
numeracy = [55,70,75,79,48]
technology = [77,64,55,82,52]

count = 0

for counter in range(len(literacy)):
  if literacy[counter] >= 75 and numeracy[counter] >= 75 and technology[counter] >= 75:
    count = count + 1
        

print(count)
```

**output (should result 7)**

```
1
```

**second version**

```
literacy = [42,72,80,82,76]
numeracy = [55,70,75,79,48]
technology = [77,64,55,82,52]

count = 0

for counter in range(len(literacy)):
  if literacy[counter] >= 75:
    count = count + 1
  if numeracy[counter] >= 75:
    count = count + 1
  if technology[counter] >= 75:
    count = count + 1
        
print(count)
```

**output**

```
7
```

Any advise how to fix the first version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first version, It's iterated only 5 times so if you increment values by `1` you will not get the expected result `7`. So the fixing of first version is your second version itself.

Here is another attempt from me.

```
count = 0
for i in literacy + numeracy + technology:
    if i >= 75:
        count = count + 1
```

In one line code,

```
In [1]: len([i for i in literacy + numeracy + technology if i >= 75])
Out[1]: 7
```